# Optimisation of matrix in R

Tags: r, optimization, calibration, demographics

I'm new to optimisation/calibration of models in R, but i'm eager to learn and really need some help. My question relates to demographic modelling.

I've done some research and found help [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136787/r-constrained-optimization-for-a-function-taking-a-matrix) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421003/optimization-of-values-in-a-matrix) but neither have quite answered my question.

I have a matrix of scalars (propensities) where each column must total to 1. These propensities are used to estimate the number of households that would arise from a given population (persons by age). The propensities model tends to overestimate the number of households in history (for which I know the true number of households).

I want to calibrate the model to minimise the error in the number of households by tweaking the propensities such that the columns still add to 1 and propensities with an initial value of zero must remain zero.

Simple example:

```
  # Propensities matrix
  mtx <- matrix(c(0.00,  0.00,  0.85,  0.00,  0.15, 0.35,  0.45,  0.00,  
               0.20,  0.00, 0.65,  0.15,  0.00,  0.20,  0.00), ncol = 3)

  # Population by age cohort
  pop <- c(2600, 16200, 13400)

  # True number of households
  target <- c(7000, 4500, 5500)

  # Function to optimise
  hh <- function(mtx, pop, target) {
    # Estimate living arrangements
    x <- mtx %*% pop 
    # Estimate number of households using parent cohorts (1,2 and 4)
    x <- c(x[1,1]/2, x[2,1]/2, x[4,1]) - target
    return(x)
  }
```

I haven't included any of my code for the optimisation/calibration step as it would be embarrassing and I've haven't been able to get anything to work!

Ideally i will have one set of propensities that generalises well for lots of different regions at the end of this process. Any advice on how i should go about achieving it? Helpful links?

**Update**

The snippet of code below executes the local search method as suggested by Enrico.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(NMOF)

data <- list(mtx = matrix(c(0.00,  0.00,  0.90,  0.00,  0.10, 0.25,  0.50,  0.00,   
                            0.25,  0.00, 0.60,  0.20,  0.00,  0.20,  0.00), ncol = 3),
             pop = c(2600, 16200, 13400),
             target = c(7190, 4650, 5920))

# True mtx
mtx.true <- matrix(c(0.00,  0.00,  0.75,  0.00,  0.25, 0.35,  0.45,  0.00,
                     0.20,  0.00, 0.65,  0.15,  0.00,  0.20,  0.00), ncol = 3)

# Function to optimise
households <- function(x, data) {

  # Estimate living arrangements
  z <- x %*% data$pop 

  # Estimate number of households using parent cohorts (1,2 and 4)
  z <- c(z[1,1]/2, z[2,1]/2, z[4,1]) - data$target
  sum(abs(z))

}

# Local search function to perturb propensities
neighbour <- function(x, data) {

  # Choose random column from mtx
  i <- sample(1:ncol(x), 1)
  # Select two non-zero propensities from mtx column
  j <- which(x[, i] != 0) %>% sample(2, replace = FALSE)

  # Randomnly select one to perturb positively 
  x[j[1], i] <- 0.1 * (1 - x[j[1], i]) + x[j[1], i]
  # Perturb second propensity to ensure mtx column adds to 1
  x[j[2], i] <- x[j[2], i] + (1 - sum(x[,i]))

  x

}

# Local search algorithm inputs 
localsearch <- list(x0 = data$mtx,             
                    neighbour = neighbour,
                    nS = 50000,                
                    printBar = FALSE)

# Execute 
now <- Sys.time()
solution <- LSopt(OF = households, algo = localsearch, data)
#> 
#> Local Search.
#> Initial solution:  2695 
#> Finished.
#> Best solution overall: 425.25
Sys.time() - now
#> Time difference of 6.33272 secs

# Inspect propensity matrices
print(solution$xbest)
#>           [,1]   [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] 0.0000000 0.3925  0.6
#> [2,] 0.0000000 0.4250  0.2
#> [3,] 0.2937976 0.0000  0.0
#> [4,] 0.0000000 0.1825  0.2
#> [5,] 0.7062024 0.0000  0.0
print(mtx.true)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] 0.00 0.35 0.65
#> [2,] 0.00 0.45 0.15
#> [3,] 0.75 0.00 0.00
#> [4,] 0.00 0.20 0.20
#> [5,] 0.25 0.00 0.00
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only comment on the optimisation part.

The code you have provided is sufficient; only your objective function evaluates to a vector. You will need to transform this vector into a single number that is to be minimised, such as the sum of squares or of absolute values.

When it comes to methods, I would try heuristics; in fact, I would try a Local-Search method. These methods operate on the solution through functions which you define; thus, you may code your solution as a matrix. More specifically, you would need two functions: the objective function (which you essentially have) and a neighbourhood function, which takes as input a solution and modifies it. In your particular case, it could take a matrix, select two none-zero elements from one column, and increase one and decrease the other. Thus, the column sum would remain unchanged.

Perhaps the tutorial http://enricoschumann.net/files/NMOF_Rmetrics2012.pdf is of interest, with R code http://enricoschumann.net/files/NMOF_Rmetrics2012.R .

Comment: Thank you Enrico. Your explanation was very helpful. I often get tripped up with the terminology, now that i have those key terms i can do some further digging. I appreciate your time and effort! :)